# OxygenXML: add an ad hoc attribute to teiCorpus framework

Tags: xml, oxygenxml

I use `teiCorpus` framework in Oxygen XML editor (version 19.1) to encode a Ugaritic corpus in Latin characters. I would like to add an ad-hoc attribute--that doesn't exist in `TEI`: `correspUnic`. Is it possible and how to do it? I think I need to use `ODD`, however, I am an `ODD` neophyte.

The goal of this attribute is to add Unicode character(s) by opposition to the latin transliteration. It will be used in elements such as `<w>`, `<g>`, `<name>`, i.e.:

```
 <w type="verb" ana="..." xml:id="..." correspUnic="UNICODE CHARACTER" >LATIN TRANSLITERATION</w>
```

In advance, thank you for your help.

Comment: I have looked at other `element` and `attribute` but they don't work. I am currently working on an argumentation to explain why they are not relevant to the cuneiform script, and why `@correspUni` should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I am hoping to understand your problem better. You are transcribing Ugaritic texts (using EpiDoc? or tei_all?) in oXygen, yes? And you would like to indicate a Latin tansliteration for each … word? character? sentence? If that is the case, a new attribute may not be necessary (although might still be something you want to do just for ease of encoding), as that sort of 1-to-1 correspondence is exactly what `@corresp` is intended for.

E.g. (I know nothing about Ugaritic, so the following example has no meaning):

```
<w type="adj" ana="silly" correspUnic="">blort</w>
```

If that is the case, then a standard TEI encoding might be

```
  <w type="adge" ana="silly" xml:lang="ugr-Ugar">
    <c corresp="#ctl_b"></c>
    <c corresp="#ctl_l"></c>
    <supplied xml:lang="ugr-Latn">o</supplied>
    <c corresp="#ctl_r"></c>
    <c corresp="#ctl_t"></c>
  </w>
```

Where the pointer "#ctl_t" point to a `<char>` element in the teiHeader/encodingDesc/charDecl. The (minor) disadvantage here is that you do have to set up a list of `<char>` elements to define characters that (for the most part) everyone already knows and are kinda obvious.

Worth noting (with no insult intended to Stackoverflow, which is *wonderful*), the normal place to post such a question is [the TEI mailing list](https://listserv.brown.edu/?A0=TEI-L%20TEI-L%20mailing%20list), where hundreds of TEI users, many of whom know much more about epigraphy than I, are likely to see it.

If kind of approach, or some other standard TEI mechanism will not do, or if you really want a `@van:latin` attribute just to make encoding faster and easier to proofread, it is not hard to do in ODD, and many folks on TEI-L would not mind stepping you through that.

Comment: Thank you @Syd for your answer and suggestion. I will look to it. I had a discussion yesterday with Elisa regarding the other possibilities. I am currently drafting an email to explain why `@corresp` may not be appropriate here. But of course, I am maybe wrong.

Comment: Regarding your questions: I'm using `teiCorpus` framework in OxygenXML. I'm doing a Latin transliteration of each word of each line. Cuneiform script has more than 3000 signs. By saying that, I'm not only suggesting an attribute only for Ugaritic but for cuneiform script which includes Sumerian, Ugaritic, Hittite, Babylonian...